# Telerik scheduler appointments in different colors

Tags: telerik, scheduler

I'm reading the appointments form a datatable. Here is my code:

```
       List<MyClass> myObjects = (from e in myEntities.Mytable where
                              e.DateFrom >= schedulerInfo.ViewStart &&
                              e.DateTo <= schedulerInfo.ViewEnd
                              select e).ToList();


        List<Appointment> appointments = new List<Appointment>(myObjects.Count);
        foreach (MyClass e in myObjects) {
            Appointment a = new Appointment();
            a.ID = e.ID;
            a.Subject = e.Description;
            a.Start = e.DateFrom;
            a.End = e.DateTo;
            a.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            appointments.Add(a);
```

and when I run it, it isn't yellow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the color of an appointment in the RadScheduler you will have to subscribe to the [OnAppointmentDataBound event](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scheduler-appointmentdatabound.html). As can be seen in [this documentation article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scheduler-appearance-setting-appointment-style.html), all you have to do is grab the current appointment objects from `e.Appointment` and define the BackColor (and other available properties) and you should be all set!

Comment: How are you databinding to the RadScheduler? Additionally, are you subscribing to the OnAppoitnmentDataBound event either via your markup or by adding the event handler in the code-behind?

Comment: Actually AppointmentDataBound will not fire if you use a Web Service to populate RadScheduler. I should've used OnClientAppointmentDataBound instead.